# Overriding a specific non-abstract function from class depending on a certain situation

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class that makes **async requests** and parses the returned jason (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29)

```
public class JSONparser extends AsyncTask<NameValuePair, Void, JSONObject>{

    // Response from the HTTP Request
    static InputStream httpResponseStream = null;
    // JSON Response String to create JSON Object
    static String jsonString = "";

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(NameValuePair... pairs) {

        try {
            // get a Http client

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            String method = pairs[0].getValue();
            String url = pairs[1].getValue();

            for(int i=2; i < pairs.length; i++){
                params.add(pairs[i]);
            }

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // If required HTTP method is POST
            if (method == "POST") {
                // Create a Http POST object
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // Encode the passed parameters into the Http request
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                // Execute the request and fetch Http response
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // Extract the result from the response
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                // Open the result as an input stream for parsing
                httpResponseStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
            // Else if it is GET
            else if (method == "GET") {
                // Format the parameters correctly for HTTP transmission
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                // Add parameters to url in GET format
                url += "?" + paramString;
                // Execute the request
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                // Execute the request and fetch Http response
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                // Extract the result from the response
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                // Open the result as an input stream for parsing
                httpResponseStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
            // Catch Possible Exceptions
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create buffered reader for the httpResponceStream
            BufferedReader httpResponseReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpResponseStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // String to hold current line from httpResponseReader
            String line = null;
            // Clear jsonString
            jsonString = "";
            // While there is still more response to read
            while ((line = httpResponseReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Add line to jsonString
                jsonString += (line + "\n");
            }
            // Close Response Stream
            httpResponseStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            // Create jsonObject from the jsonString and return it
            return new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            // Return null if in error
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

and what I'd like to do is to know how I can change **onPreExecute()** and **onPostExecute()** (from the hyperlink above:

> **onPreExecute()**, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.
>       **doInBackground(Params...)**, invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>   to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>   parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>   result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>   passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>   These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>       **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)**, invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.
>       **onPostExecute(Result)**, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>   computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

accordingly to what I need to do in a certain part of the code called like this

```
**** code ****
//treat onPreExecute here
//treat onPostExecute here
JSONObject returned = new JSONparser().execute(method,httpurl,"").get(); //commit
```

Comment: None of it will matter if you don't compare your strings correctly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @ajb solved, ty for pointing that out mate <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create sub classes of `JSONparser` which override `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute`, and instantiate them, or you can create an anonymous sub class which overrides them :

```
JSONObject returned = new JSONparser () {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // some logic here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // some logic here
    }

}.execute(method,httpurl,"").get();
```